# Jasper reports field from java class

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have a Java project that uses the Jasper reports to generate reports after the upgrade to Java 8 iReports stopped working, I updated the design dependancy and started using Jasper Report Studio to make the edits , to all well , the problem is that when for example add a new field to a class in Java, Jasper Report Studio can not "see" changes in IReport I just put the compiled classes on the classpath and worked, any change in the class was seen the reports editor , how do this in Jasper Report Studio ? I'm using the standalone version.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, JasperReport does not support Java 8 yet

[community.jaspersoft.com/questions/824715/ireport-compatibility-java8](http://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/824715/ireport-compatibility-java8)

Comment: As i said, now we are using Jaspersoft Studio.